# How can I achieve the realtime clouds/sky effect of Lumion?

Tags: sky, volumetric-light

Does anyone know how they do this? They're not truly volumetric - you can't fly through them - it's still a texture.

http://vimeo.com/16534222

It looks like it's a perlin based solution, but I really can't work out how they get the fantastic lighting! How can I achieve this effect?

To be clear, I'm not talking about the sky (which would be a variation on CIE/Preetham) or sun shafts or any other effect - i'm talking purely about the clouds, which are rendered straight to the skybox texture.

Answer (score 3):

For realtime fog/cloud rendering you can take a look at this article [from GPU Gems 3](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch30.html).

If you are looking for Sky / Atmospheric Rendering, over [at vterrain](http://vterrain.org/Atmosphere/) they have a nice collection of articles.

For light/sun scattering I suggest you take a look at the blog of [Fabien](http://www.fabiensanglard.net/lightScattering/index.php) and again [GPU Gems 3](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch13.html)